# my app can not search in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.me.tippingadvicer
This is my little app in google play store and I wanna try this small little app to learn how to upload app to google play store . However , after I upload the app to google play store , I can see it on this link but it's invisible when I search my app name in google play store even I swide to the bottom of the page . Or maybe it's too inrrelevent?

Comment: As No One mentioned below it takes some time to index your application for Google Play store, so it will be available in search results, but the search output algorithms may not place it on the first pages.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 24/48 hours to get visible on the PlayStore.

There’s no need to worry about that.

Comment: It's been far longer than 24/48 hours. The app does not show up on the play store.

Comment: @MikeK try clearing playstore app’s cache, alternatively type in the package name of your app in playstore search. :)

Comment: The only way my app shows up is when I add an underscore at any point in the app name, whether it be a prefix, suffix, or inbetween characters. I've contacted Google support about this, let's see what they say.